# Civimail 'Send test email to group' allows sending mailings to groups for which 'Mailing list' has been disabled

Tags: civimail

Though for a group the 'Mailing list' option has been disabled the 'Send test email to group' function still allows you to select these groups (version 4.6.16).

There also isn't a option to disable this test function for certain groups, I've seen users use this test function to send out the mailing. Of course that is not the purpose of this test so it would be great if I could disable it per group.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of CiviCRM are you using? Version 4.6 adds a "preview" window that shows you exactly who will recieve the test mailing to prevent mistakes:

[image: CiviMail]

Comment: I'm already using version 4.6. I guess users would have some trouble finding the 'Next' button, you wouldn't expect it on the left side of the screen. That's probably why some of my users click the 'Send test' button and use this to send the mailing. I don't think this is the purpose of a test button.

Comment: If you don't like the civimail layout there are alternatives to pick from.

Comment: What do you mean with alternatives? Are there layout templates I can select?

Comment: https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/civimail-ui-refresh-for-v46

Comment: Ok thx, now I know there are 3 options but how to configure either of them?

Comment: Currently there's no configuration option. You just have to change it in the url bar. An admin setting or per-user setting would be a nice feature to add.